# Oracle Browser Issues

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

Are there any browser issues with Oracle, specifically IE7, IE8 and Firefox? I.T. has told me that I have to build all my sites to support IE6 because IE6 works with their version of Oracle.

They've said that some of their apps break on newer browsers. Can someone let me know if this is true or provide me with a link to verify this. Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have to list the Oracle apps you are talking about for anyone to provide specific answers.  Application Express uses tons of Javascript for example.  I don't know if older versions of Oracle Forms use certain IE6 features, but if that is your question you should tell people so they can help.

Comment: Thanks MJB, this is the part that sucks I don't know what Oracle apps they are running :( I think their just trying to give me the run-around. I've built the site to work on modern browsers (the latest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari) and they want me to do a version for IE6. I'm just trying to figure out what the issues are their talking about. I know it's difficult but is there anything that you can suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot.  I can however tell you that if they have applications that ONLY work under IE6, they probably also have plans to upgrade their own apps.  And I would think it is fair for you to ask them what apps you have to test to make sure they work with whatever browser you want to use.  Good luck otherwise -- I have nothing.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll see what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle Apps suite 11i is [certified](http://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/2009/10/internet_explorer_8_certified_ebs11i.html) for IE8
But Oracle have a whole bunch of older technologies plus stuff that they have acquired recently.